# Multiple scroll view android

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview and above that there is a relative layout which contains an image .I want to scroll listview and the above layout at same time ? is  it possible ?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sss" />
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topbarsecond"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#d6d7da"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the RelativeLayout as HeaderView of ExpandableListView.

```
ListView#addHeaderView(View v)
```

Please refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29).

Answer (score 2):

Just put all your views (including ListView) into a layout and then put it to a ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Since a list already has a scrollview by default adding another scrollview may not work properly,hence try to put a separate scrollview in the enclosing layout without a listview,which may solve your purpose.